# Attracting new users

Tags: discussion

A quick look at the new users statistics gave the following chart:

[image: new users stats]

[image: Active vs. first-timers]

Worrisome. Would somebody familiar with other betas dispel the impression, please?

What can we do to attract more people here?

Comment: [This is normal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kBhuQ.png)

Comment: Stats from QuantCast: https://www.quantcast.com/space.stackexchange.com (hat tip to TildalWave).

Comment: Simply? Wait. It takes a while for news to spread to those who might be interested in it and it can take a while to get up to speed before the snowball effect kicks in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure there's much to dispel; the pattern seems pretty typical. You start with a small private beta and a big spike from the hoopla of the public launch. The spike peaks as incoming users check out the site — and slowly drift off over the next few weeks as curious onlookers move on to other things.

Eventually you settle into your core group of users who will (hopefully) stick around for the long term. That's where your avid userbase will begin to grow as you ask high-quality questions that attract new users in through search. You're not quite up to that stage of measurable, steady growth, but it's completely normal and nothing to be alarmed about.

Comment: Robert, you forgot to include a link to your blog post: [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/). ;)