# Does this site have a good chance to "survive" the beta period?

Tags: discussion, public-beta

Partially related to [this question](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/attracting-new-users).

Space.SE exists for about a month now. Traffic numbers (like questions/par, e.t.c.) don't seem to be bad, but some of them may not be satisfied. What are this site's current chances that it will even exist in a year's time?

Also, when can it (or any SE sites) go out of beta?

Comment: I think the chances are very good.

Comment: [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) [SE] blog post by @RobertCartaino ♦ ;)

Comment: As mentioned in the Cartaino post, [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration) has some indicators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traffic numbers are the least important, especially this early, of the stats. There is still a good number of questions coming, and traffic will build up with time, it just takes a while, that's all. I don't think this site is in any danger for the time being.

If you are worried, just make sure to ask good questions, give good answers, and upvote stuff. Also, spread the word!

Comment: I'm not worrying, I just asked. Also, the best I can do is asking, but as you may have seen, I do it well. =)